# Why does passing option.as_ref behave differently than using a match block and mapping the inner to ref myself?

Tags: rust

I stumbled upon strange behavior that I can't make sense of yet.
I have the following function:

```rust
pub fn complete(self) {
    let last_value: Option<BasicValueEnum<'ctx>> = self.last_value.into_inner();
    // self.builder.build_return(last_value.as_ref()); // <- does not work

    match last_value {
        Some(value) => {
            self.builder.build_return(Some(&value)); // <- works
        },
        None => { self.builder.build_return(None); },
    }

    self.function.verify(true);
}
```

where `self.builder.build_return` has the following signature:

```rust
pub fn build_return(&self, value: Option<&dyn BasicValue<'ctx>>) -> InstructionValue<'ctx>
```

Now, the builder comes from a library so I don't know much about the specifics, but just looking at the signatures this behavior looks quite strange to me. Shouldn't `Option.as_ref()` return a `Option<&T>`, which in my case should be the same as what my match expression does?

I have the strong feeling that I'm missing some concept instead of that I've encountered some bug.

If it helps, the builder comes from the inkwell library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the working code, the compiler sees that `&value` has to be of type `&dyn BasicValue<'ctx>` and can coerce it.

But with [`Option::as_ref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.as_ref) with signature `fn(&self) -> Option<&T>` there is no [coercion](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-coercions.html#type-coercions) possible because it always converts `&Option<T>` into `Option<&T>`, therefore the types are different,
one is `Option<&BasicValueEnum<'ctx>>` the other is `Option<&dyn BasicValue<'ctx>>`.

To make it work with `as_ref` you can manually cast the concrete reference into a reference to a trait object:

```rust
self.builder.build_return(last_value.as_ref().map(|x| x as _));
```

Where `_` can be derived by the compiler to be `&dyn BasicValue<'ctx>`

Comment: Alternatively there's `as_deref` which might work.

Comment: Not in [one of the combiations I considered](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f1d757db28341542485d05526bb3fb2f).